# SQL Server trigger operation with out cursor

Tags: sql, sql-server, cursor

I have a scenario where in I have to generate SQL script after every DML operation. We have a trigger that runs after every Insert, Update, Delete.

Primarily it takes data from Inserted/Deleted tables and generates a SQL script for each row and performs an insert in to another table.

For example, If we insert

1. Take all inserted values
2. Open a cursor
3. For each inserted row, generate a SQL script that will be inserted in to another table for audit purpose
4. close cursor.

This trigger is taking almost 4-5 hours for 10,000 rows of 5 columns. Columns are `int`, `date` and `varchar(100)`.

We are trying to replace the trigger. Need suggestions on same.

```
Set @syncScript = 'Insert Into table('

            Declare insertCursor Cursor Local Forward_Only For
            Select a, b, c From Inserted

            Open insertCursor

            Fetch Next From insertCursor Into @a, @b, @c

            While (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
            Begin
                Declare @valuesList varchar(max)

                Set @columnList = ''
                Set @paramsList = '['
                Set @valuesList = ''

                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col6, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(dbo.ConvertFloatToVarchar(col6), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.a= @a And I.b= @b And I.c= @c And 1 = 1
                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col5, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col5), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.a= @a And I.b= @b And I.c= @c And 1 = 1
                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col4, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col4), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.a= @a And I.b= @b And I.c= @c And 1 = 1
                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col3, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col3), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.a= @a And I.b= @b And I.c= @c And 1 = 1
                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col2, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col2), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.a= @a And I.b= @b And I.c= @c And 1 = 1
                Select @columnList = @columnList + 'col1, ', @paramsList = @paramsList + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col1), 'NULL') + ''', ', @valuesList = @valuesList + '?, ' From Inserted I Where I.TraitValueMemberId = @a And I.ValueSetId = @b And I.LanguageCulture = @c And 1 = 1

                Set @columnList = SUBSTRING(@columnList, 1, Len(@columnList) - 1) + ') Values ('
                Set @valuesList = SUBSTRING(@valuesList, 1, Len(@valuesList) - 1) + ')'
                Set @paramsList = @paramsList + ']'
                Set @bigScript = (COALESCE(@syncScript, '') + COALESCE(@columnList, '') + COALESCE(@valuesList, ''))



                            Insert Into Log (CreatedDate, [Message]) Select GetDate(), 'tablename INSERT syncScript = ' + @bigScript +'paramsList = ' + COALESCE(@paramsList, '')

                Insert Into [dbo].[LogAudit] (GuidId, Query, Params, TableName, CreatedDate, Operation, UserId)
                Values ('00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000', @bigScript, @paramsList, @table, GetDate(), @operation, @debugUser)

                Fetch Next From insertCursor Into @a, @b, @c
            End

            Close insertCursor
            Deallocate insertCursor
```

In case of update we join across inserted and deleted tables to generate update script like shown above.

Comment: Can you explain why you're using a cursor and dynamic SQL? Why aren't you just directly inserting from inserted into your table?

Comment: Well, for starts, you don't need to do it row by row. Since what you're inserting into the tables is basically static (always col6, col5, col4... etc), you can simplify it to something like: `INSERT [Log] (CreatedDate, [Message]) SELECT GETDATE(), 'tablename INSERT syncScript = INSERT INTO TABLE (col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1) VALUES (''' + COALESCE(dbo.ConvertFloatToVarchar(col6), 'NULL') + ''', ''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col5), 'NULL')... FROM inserted` etc

Comment: @pmbaustin we generate the insert that will be synched to our mobile device and processed for updates there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved the issue using SET Operation rather than Trigger

```
INSERT Into [dbo].[LogAudit] (GuidId, Query, Params, TableName, CreatedDate, Operation, UserId)
            SELECT '00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000',  
                 'INSERT INTO Table(col6, col5, col4, col3, col2, col1) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)', 
            '[' +   '''' + COALESCE(dbo.ConvertFloatToVarchar(col6), 'NULL') + ''','  + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col5), 'NULL') + ''', ' +  '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col4), 'NULL') + ''', ' + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col3), 'NULL') + ''', ' + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col2), 'NULL') + ''', ' +  '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col1), 'NULL') + ''', ' + ']', @table, GetDate(), @operation, @debugUser FROM Inserted

            -- Insert into Log
            Insert Into Log (CreatedDate, [Message]) Select GetDate(), 'MTDE_TraitValueMemberByLanguage_Sync INSERT 
                    syncScript = INSERT Into [dbo].[LogAudit (GuidId, Query, Params, TableName, CreatedDate, Operation, UserId) VALUES VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)' + 
                    'paramsList = '  +  '[' +   '''' + COALESCE(dbo.ConvertFloatToVarchar(col6), 'NULL') + ''','  + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col5), 'NULL') + ''', ' +  '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col4), 'NULL') + ''', ' + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col3), 'NULL') + ''', ' + '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col2), 'NULL') + ''', ' +  '''' + COALESCE(Convert(varchar(max), col1), 'NULL') + ''', ' + ']' FROM Inserted
```